# Nested loop with synchronous and asynchronous behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, callback

The problem is as follows. I have an array of objects like so:

```
let myObj = [
{'db1':['doc1','doc2','doc3']},
{'db2':['doc4','doc5']},
{'db3':['doc7','doc8','doc9','doc10']}
]
```

Note that this is a data structure I decided to use for the problem and can be changed if it can improve the overall implementation. The actual db and document ids are read from a text file formatted as below.

```
"db1","doc1"
"db1","doc2"
...
```

My app will iterate through the db list synchronously. Inside each db iteration, there will be an asynchronous iteration of the document list. Each document will be retrieved, processed and saved back to the db.

So basically at any given instance: one db, but multiple documents.

I have a working implementation of the above like so:

**dbIterator**: the synchronous outer loop to iterate dbs. The callback passed to `docIterator` will trigger the next iteration.

```
const dbIterator = function (x) {
  if (x < myObj.length) {
    let dbObj = myObj[x];
    let dbId = Object.keys(dbObj)[0];
    docIterator(dbId, dbObj[dbId], ()=>dbIterator(x+1));
  } else {
    logger.info('All dbs processed');
  }
};
```

**docIterator**: the asynchronous loop to iterate docs. The callback `cb` is called after all documents are processed. This is tracked via the `docsProcessed` and `docsToBeProcessed` variables

```
const docIterator = function(dbId, docIds, cb){
  //create connection
  targetConnection = //some config for connection to dbId
  let docsProcessed = 0;
  let docsToBeProcessed = docIds.length;

  //asynchronous iteration of documents
  docIds.forEach((docId)=>{
    getDocument(docId, targetConnection).then((doc)=>{
      //process document
      processDoc(doc, targetConnection).then(()=>{
        //if processing is successful
        if (++docsProcessed >= docsToBeProcessed) {
          cb();
        }
      })
       //if processing fails
      .catch((e) => {
        logger.error('error when processing document');
        if (++docsProcessed >= docsToBeProcessed) {
          cb();
        }
      });

    }).catch((e)=>{
      logger.error('error when retrieving document: ');
      if (++docsProcessed >= docsToBeProcessed) {
        cb();
      }
    });
  });
};
```

**processDoc:** used to process and save an individual document. This returns a promise that gets resolved when the document processing is done which in turn increments `docsProcessed` and conditionally (`docsProcessed >= docsToBeProcessed`) calls the call back passed into `docIterator`

```
const processDoc = function(doc, targetConnection) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(shouldThisDocBeProcessed(doc){
      let updatedDoc = logic(doc);
      targetConnection.insert(updatedDoc, updatedDoc._id,
        function (error, response) {
          if (!error){
            logger.info('updated successfully');
          } else {
            logger.error('error when saving doc');
          }
          resolve();
        }
      );
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  })
};
```

This works as expected but for me this implementation is sub-optimal and messy. I'm pretty sure this can be improved upon and most importantly a chance to better understand and implement solutions to synchronous and asynchronous problems.

I'm open to constructive criticism. So how can this be improved?

Comment: What's this `docs` variable inside `docIterator`?

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo sorry that was a typo.  It should be docsId. corrected

Answer (score 4):

**First** you can make the database container more precise and accessible if you define it like this:

```
var dbs = [
    { id: 'db1', docs: ['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3'] },
    { id: 'db2', docs: ['doc4', 'doc5', 'doc6'] },
];
```

So you can access the database id via db.id and don't need to calculate it with `dbId = Object.keys(dbObj)[0]`

**Second** the function's names aren't so good. The names `dbIterator`, `docIterator` and `merchantIterator` tell about HOW they do their work, but they should better tell WHAT they do as it is the case with `getDocument`.

**Third** in `docIterator` you are nesting promises but they are meant for chaining.

**Fourth** in `docIterator` the checks `if (++docsProcessed >= docsToBeProcessed)` are needless because `forEach` makes sure that all documents will be processed and it will stop if there are no more.

When you are dealing with loops and asynchronous functions you should have a look at the `Promise.all` method. Provided that `merchantIterator` does realy nothing more than triggering the next iteration (as you suggested) I think the processing of all databases and documents may look like this:

```
function processDatabases(dbs) {
    Promise.all(dbs.map(db => {
        var connection = // some config for connection to **db.id**
        return Promise.all(db.docs.map(doc => {
            return getDocument(doc, connection)
                .then(doc => processDoc(doc, connection))
                .catch(err => logger.error(err.message));
        }));
    }))
    .then(() => logger.info('all done'));
}
```

In this case `getDocument` and `processDoc` should reject or throw an `Error` with an appropriate message.

Comment: thank you for the response. The fourth point: I do the incremental  condition check to identify when all asynchronous operations are complete. The forEach completion does not guarantee the completion of the async tasks.

Promise.all will not work in this case as I need to know when all promises complete even if some get rejected. As per my understanding, promise.All does not wait if one promise rejects

Comment: Okay but my promise never rejects it resolves in all cases. So am i good to go in that case? Or can there still be e rejection in case of any unseen rejections that I have not handled. I'm thinking some sort of an exception.